# Why do changes to a list alter another list within ViewModel, too?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, data-class

I have an ArrayList

```
val tasks = remember { mutableStateListOf<TaskItem>() }
```

where the TaskItem is

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class Task(
    var task: String,
    var done: Boolean = false
) : Parcelable
```

and

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class TaskItem(var id: String, var task: Task) : Parcelable
```

When I enter the target Screen, pass some data into the `tasks`:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    tasks.clear()
    tasks.addAll(data.tasks)
    Log.wtf("TST_data.tasks", data.tasks.map(TaskItem::task).toString())
    // Logs: TST_data.tasks     [Task(task=Broccoli , done=true)]
}
```

where, the `data` is driven by a DataModel calss:

```
class DataModel(private val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    ....
    val tasks = mutableStateListOf<TaskItem>()
    ....
}
```

So far is verything ok, but after making some changes to the `tasks`, let's say I changed the value of `done` to the `false` and I do it like this:

```
...
onDone = { index ->
    tasks[index] = tasks.onDone(index)
}
...
```

and here is the `onDone` extension:

```
fun List<TaskItem>.onDone(index: Int): TaskItem {
    val item = this[index]
    val tmpTask = item.task
    return item.copy(task = tmpTask.copy(done = !tmpTask.done))
}
```

After that I want to save the changes before leaving the screen. To make sure that there are some changes, I compare the lists like this:

```
if(data.tasks.map(TaskItem::task) != tasks.map(TaskItem::task))
    // proceed with saving in Room
else
    // a toast massage: No changes made.
```

The problem is, it goes into `else` block, which means there are no changes although I made a change. I tried to log those lists to see the lements before calling the `if` statement:

```
Log.wtf("TST_data.tasks", data.tasks.map(TaskItem::task).toString())
Log.wtf("TST_tasks", tasks.map(TaskItem::task).toString())
```

Here is the result:

```
TST_data.tasks [Task(task=Broccoli , done=false)]
TST_tasks     [Task(task=Broccoli , done=false)]
```

Chnaged value within `tasks` changed also the value in within `data.tasks`, which is not possible, since I do note change anything within `data.tasks`.

As you can see, that the `data.tasks` changes whenever I change `tasks`.

This should be impossible! Why do it happen and how do I prevent that chnage?

Comment: How come it's logging `Task` when your list contains `TaskItem`?

Comment: Even if they are different lists, they hold exactly the same items. If you change an item in one list it changes it also in the other because it points to the same object. You will need to make a deep copy of the list to prevent this

Comment: @k314159 I sorry, I missed this in the code: `(data.)tasks.map(TaskItem::task).toString()`. I edited the question, too.

Comment: @Ivo how does the one list point to another, when they meet each other only once when the data is loaded. Aftert that is the data.tasks never used in the screen. I do not understand. Is there any example, to get it properly understood? Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you showed some relevant code that you have in the `if` part (where you commented "// proceed with saving") - in particular, how are you updating `data.tasks` once you've saved the task list?

Comment: @k314159 I just save the changes in the Room database.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the same item (reference to an instance of DataModel) into two different lists, both lists are pointing at the same instance. If you modify that instance by changing one of its `var` properties, both lists will see the same change because they’re looking at the same instance.

For this reason, you cannot compare old and new versions of your data without doing what is a called a deep copy. It would look something like this to copy each individual instance in the list as you create the new list:

```
list.map { it.copy() }
```

Of course, you have to do this *before* you mutate the items in the list. And it gets considerably more complicated if any of the items inside your model class *also* have `var` properties in them. This is all very error prone, which is why it’s recommended not to use any `var` properties inside any of your model classes. They should be immutable classes instead. When you need to change something you replace an item in the list with a copy that has the change applied. This is why Kotlin data classes provide convenient `copy()` functions that allow you to change specific property values as you make the copy.

Aside from being error prone, it also breaks Compose’s State functionality for the same reason. State can’t detect changes that are coming from mutated classes because when they are mutated, the information about previous state is lost and cannot be compared for it to be able to detect a change.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I just added one more pice of code for a `onDone` extension, how the changes are made within the `tasks` list. I use a deep copy indeed. Or I am wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: That looks ok but I don’t know how you are using that onDone lambda. By the way, calling toList after map is redundant. `map` already returns a new List.

Comment: That onDOne lambda is triggered once a button is clicked in the LazyColumn, which returs the index of clicked item.